# Face detection with back camera is not working properly using camera2 API

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I am using camre2 api for face detection. This is working fine for the front camera but it is not working with the back camera.
Can anyone please proved face detection matrix for the back camera

Front camera face detection matrix is

```
 if (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {


                        StreamConfigurationMap map = mCameraCharacteristics.get(
                                CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                        if (map == null) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                        Size largest = Collections.max(
                                Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                                new CompareSizesByArea());
                        /*maxImages = mCameraCharacteristics.get(
                                CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT);*/
                        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                                ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
                        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                                mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                        // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                        // coordinate.
                        int displayRotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                        //noinspection ConstantConditions
                        mSensorOrientation = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                        mSwappedDimensions = false;

                        switch (displayRotation) {
                            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                                if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                                    mSwappedDimensions = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                                if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                                    mSwappedDimensions = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                        }

                        Point displaySize = new Point();
                        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                        int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                        int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                        int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                        int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

                        if (mSwappedDimensions) {
                            rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                            rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                            maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                            maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                        }

                        if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                            maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                        }

                        if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                            maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                        }

                        // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                        // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                        // garbage capture data.
                        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                                rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                                maxPreviewHeight, largest);

                        // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                            textureView.setAspectRatio(
                                    mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                        } else {
                            textureView.setAspectRatio(
                                    mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                        }

                        // Check if the flash is supported.
                        Boolean available = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                        FlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                        this.cameraId = "0";

                        int orientationOffset = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                        Rect activeArraySizeRect = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

                        // Face Detection Matrix
                        mFaceDetectionMatrix = new Matrix();
                        // TODO - I guess that is not enough if we have a landscape layout too...
                        mFaceDetectionMatrix.setRotate(orientationOffset);

                        Log.i("Test", "activeArraySizeRect1: (" + activeArraySizeRect + ") -> " + activeArraySizeRect.width() + ", " + activeArraySizeRect.height());
                        Log.i("Test", "activeArraySizeRect2: " + mPreviewSize.getWidth() + ", " + mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                        float s1 = mPreviewSize.getWidth() / (float)activeArraySizeRect.width();
                        float s2 = mPreviewSize.getHeight() / (float)activeArraySizeRect.height();
                        //float s1 = mOverlayView.getWidth();
                        //float s2 = mOverlayView.getHeight();
                        boolean mirror = true; // we always use front face camera
                        boolean weAreinPortrait = true;
                        mFaceDetectionMatrix.postScale(mirror ? -s1 : s1, s2);
                        if (mSwappedDimensions) {
                            mFaceDetectionMatrix.postTranslate(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                        } else {
                            // TODO - ...

                           // here i am using same code just making mirror 
                           //value false.
                        }

                    }
```

This is working fine for front camera. Can any one have solution for back camera face detection matrix.

Comment: Can any one have solution for this issue

Comment: do you have any sample code to detect the faces on both rear and front camera.. share me your code example..

Answer (score 0):

use boolean mirror = false for else condition in  if (facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)